# dynamically adding data in perl

Tags: perl

can anybody please explain the difference between adding information to an array dynamically and adding information statically in PERL. I am quite confused on that. please? the code that i have seen for dynamically uploading data is:

```
$database{"MRD-300"} = {
    "Name"    => "Nathan Hale",
    "Address" => "999 Centennial Ave.",
    "Town"    => "AnyTown",
    "State"   => "AnyState",
    "Zip"     => "12345-1234"
};

$refCustomer = $database{"MRD-300"};

print(%{$refCustomer}->{"Name"} . "\n");
print(%{$refCustomer}->{"Address"} . "\n");
```

Comment: Your example code is using some poor perl practices. The use of `%{...}` in the `print` statements is deprecated and should be avoided. Better (and more concise) is: `print $refCustomer->{Name} . "\n"`

Comment: I'm confused too.  I completely fail to understand your distinction between dynamically/statically.  Can you show what you mean for *both*?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this counts as "adding information statically":

```
my %database;
%database = (
    "MRD-300" => { Name => ..., Address => ..., Town => ... },
    "HKQ-509" => { Name => ..., Address => ..., Town => ... },
    "BXL-994" => { Name => ..., Address => ..., Town => ... },
);
```

The same thing can be accomplished with separate assignment statements:

```
my %database;
$database{"MRD-300"} = { Name => ..., Address => ..., Town => ... };
$database{"HKQ-509"} = { Name => ..., Address => ..., Town => ... };
$database{"BXL-994"} = { Name => ..., Address => ..., Town => ... };
```